# Laravel simple route throws neverending loop in browser

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a clean Laravel installation setup with the following routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'SiteController@showIndex');


Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@showIndex');


Route::get('/admin/login', 'AdminController@showLogin');
```

And the controllers:
SiteController

```
public function showIndex()
{
    return 'default site controller... this controller is only used for frontend';
}
```

And Admincontroller:

```
public function showIndex(){
        echo 'AdminController: showindex';
    }


    public function showLogin(){
        return 'login';
    }




    public function actionAuthenicate(){
        return 'authenticate';
    }
```

The first and last route work. I get the printed line visible in the browser. But the /admin-route doesn't work. Than I get the error message my browser is in a neverending loop.

As I say, clean install so this is the only configuration yet to be found. Can someone please help me?

Kind regards,

Pim

Comment: what happens when you remove the last route and try accessing it again?

Comment: Tried that but still shows the same result. It is definitly something with the route, because when I trigger the same function with another route it works perfectly well...

Comment: do you have a folder called admin?

Comment: no, it is just a route... I don't need a folder 'admin' the problem is with the route, else the other route /admin/login shouldn't work either if I had a folder...

Comment: haha yes I do have one, now I understand what you meant :) It works fine after renaming the admin folder in /public/ Thanks!

Comment: @Ortix92, can you send in your comment as answer, than I can mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel can't generate a route if it is the name of an actual folder in your system. If you rename the folder, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing a string, you need to return it.

```
public function showIndex() {
    return 'AdminController: showindex';
}
```

But I don't know why it causes a redirect loop.

Comment: You can just easily echo a string in a controller, should be not problem... Else you could only echo in Views ;)

 public function showIndex(){
  return 'AdminController: showindex';
 }


 public function showLogin(){
  echo  'login';
 }




 public function actionAuthenicate(){
  return 'authenticate';
 }

when I call the 2nd function from my controller it just perfectly works as it should soooo that is not the point ;)